# ¿como puedo acortar un Json para mandarlo a una base de datos desde netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, restful

necesito ayuda con mi código
public String net() throws IOException{

```
   String address = "http://10.32.1.199/PortalDuno/public/api/utilerias/hashPassword";
     password = ("123456");


    String stringToSend = URLEncoder.encode(password);

    URL URL = new URL(address);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)URL.openConnection();
    //connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);


    connection.setDoOutput(true);


    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");


    connection.setReadTimeout(10*1000);

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
            connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write("password=" + stringToSend);
    out.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
    String response;
    while((response = in.readLine()) != null)
        return response;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response);
    in.close();
   return response;}
```

Lo que hace ese restful es que me manda una contraseña encriptada, la cual se almacena en la variable response, al momento de mandar esa variable a mi base de datos se manda lo siguiente:

```
{"respuesta":"success","mensaje":"","errores":[],"passwordHashed":"$2y$10$7kit4dFz\/usnAY5z9SuY1e3AXXnS8ulmxurKWZrguYAEaQUf7n9PS"}
```

Lo que yo necesito es mandar únicamente esta parte: `$2y$10$7kit4dFz\/usnAY5z9SuY1e3AXXnS8ulmxurKWZrguYAEaQUf7n9PS`

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?
se los agradecería muchísimo, llevo así 2 días.

Comment: Quieres que el servidor envié solo la contraseña encriptada, o una vez que recibas toda la respuesta, extraer la contraseña desde Json?

Comment: hola, ya logré resolver esto, lo hice con la librería org.json y fue con el siguiente método:

Comment: public Object parsearJson() throws IOException, ParseException{
    

        org.json.simple.JSONObject json = (org.json.simple.JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(response);
           System.out.println(json.get("passwordHashed"));
           Object aObj = json.get("passwordHashed");
           
  return aObj; }